# How can show my list and make it searchable? C#

Tags: c#, list, search

Ok, i'm super new to this and this is for a schoolproject.

The project is to code a program where a person can store, update and search information.

In my program i make lists which store cloth information (brand, type, color, size) and i think my information gets stored but i don't know how access it / make a search function for it.

Is my code correct? Should i use another strategy?

**This is where my list is defined(?!)**

```
public class klädDATALIST 
{
    public string märke;
    public string typ;
    public string färg;
    public string storlek;

    public klädDATALIST(string _märke, string _typ, string _färg, string _storlek)
    {
        this.märke = _märke;
        this.typ = _typ;
        this.färg = _färg;
        this.storlek = _storlek;
    }
}
```

**This is wehre the string variabels will be filled through a couple of Readline() functions.**

**For exampel:**

```
string _färg = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
```

**Then after i've saved it ill make a new list, i think?:**

```
List<klädDATALIST> newklädDataList = new List<klädDATALIST>();
            newklädDataList.Add(new klädDATALIST(_märke, _typ, _färg, _storlek));
```

I hope you can help me, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain your problem? Your code looks fine as far as I know...

Comment: If you are just trying to print out your list you can use [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) and you can print out your variables and you can also use it for searching

Comment: ok, thanks! I'm just so confused with it all, i've only coded c# for a couple of days now.

Comment: No worries and no problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements can be accessed by iterating through the collection/List.

```
foreach( var item in newklädDataList)
{
    // access or read item members.
    Console.WriteLine(item.märke);
}
```

When you want to find an element in the `List`, you can either use `Linq`

```
var item = newklädDataList.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.märke == "searchstring"); //Any key to identify list item.

if(item != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.märke);
}
```

Or use `Find`

```
var item = newklädDataList.Find(e=>e.märke == "searchstring");
```

Hope this helps!